# I need urgent help with understanding my notes; period 2 solutions

Tags: dynamical-systems

Consider the following functions:

$X_{n+1} = 2aX_na$ on $0 \leq X_n \leq \dfrac{1}{2}$

$X_{n+1} = -2aX_n + 2a$ on $\dfrac{1}{2} \leq X_n \leq$

We want to find if there are period 2 solutions for this triangular shaped 'object'. What my teacher did and what I don't understand now is:

- Normally if you want period 2 solutions you have to solve $X=X_{n+2}$, so $x= f(f(x))$. However, what my teacher I believe is combine the functions:

$x = -2a \cdot 2ax + 2a$

..  $x=\dfrac{2a}{1+4a^2}$

- Why do we have to fill in the first function in the second (or vice versa)
- Doesn't doing it the other way around yield different answers? ($x=2a(-2aX_n + 2a$))?

He then continued on with his answer $\dfrac{2a}{1+4a^2}$, and did the following:

$$0 < \dfrac{2a}{1+4a^2} < \dfrac{1}{2}$$

- Why do we have to add this restraint?